# Can sub-selects change in one single query in a read committed transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transaction, postgresql-9.5, isolation-level

I am querying the same table multiple times in a single query in a transaction with isolation level set to READ COMMITTED (which is the default in PostgreSQL). Examples are:

```
BEGIN;

WITH
first AS (SELECT * FROM table),
second AS (SELECT * FROM table)
SELECT ...;

END;
```

or

```
BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM table
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table;

END;
```

Is it possible that the first `sub-SELECT` yields other results than the second `sub-SELECT`? I understand that `SELECT` queries might yield different results when executed separately (due to the characteristics of a READ COMMITTED transaction), but I am wondering what might happen if they are embedded in the same query.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

A single query (and even a query with many sub-queries is considered a **single** query) sees a consistent state of the database as it was when that query started.

It's not even necessary to use explicit transaction control as you did.